# When should links open in new tab/window?

Tags: html, browser, tabs, navigation

When ***exactly*** links should open in a new tab/window? I find that some of the actions which require certain operations in a new tab/window can be done on the same page using ***modal windows*** and then refreshing the same page to show the updated contents.

A couple of google searches gave me the following results:

- **[Why external links should open in new tabs?](http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-external-links-should-open-in-new-tabs/)**
- **[When if ever should links be opened in a new window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31579/when-if-ever-should-links-be-opened-in-a-new-window)**
- **[Is there ever a good reason to force opening a new browser window?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13727/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-force-opening-a-new-browser-window/31319#31319)**
- **[Should links open in new windows?](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2008/07/01/should-links-open-in-new-windows/)**
- **[Forcing links to open in new windows: an argument that should have ended 15 years ago](http://www.marco.org/2014/01/10/target-blank)**

Some suggest that in case of external links they should be opened in a new tab/window, some suggest that they should be opened on the same page for simplified user control. Both of them sound correct in their own ways. Isn't there some sort of generalization? Or are there any particular situations where we cannot do without links opening in a new tab/window?

In other words, what are the situations where a link should open in a new tab/window OR in the same page (taking into account that modal windows are implemented frequently these days)?

Comment: I think this question is more suitable in UX.SE

Answer (score 2):

Having external links opened in a new tab is better and done more often so that when you have a user surfing your site and clicks on an external link he doesn't have to go back but simply just needs to close that tab and can continuous surfing your site.
You have to bare in mind that not ever internet user knows how to work with a browser like you do (Still many lesser-intelligent people on the net).

Answer (score -2):

add attribute target="_blank" on a tag

```html
<a href="http://uxmovement.com/navigation/why-external-links-should-open-in-new-tabs/" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Link 1</a></strong></p>
```

Comment: The question was **when**, not **how**.